# Build error in jenkins ERROR: Maven Home /home/app/maven-2.2.1 doesn’t exist

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am trying run `Jenkins` and Building a project.
I have install `Maven 2.2.1`. I downloaded Maven 2.2.1 and extracted in a folder Maven 2.2.1.
set the home path in `.bash_profile`.
content of `.bash_profile`

```
M2_HOME=/home/qaserver3/app/maven-2.2.1
export M2_HOME

PATH=$M2_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

when I run mvn --version on terminal, I get

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-07 00:46:01+0530)
Java version: 1.6.0_45
Java home: /home/qaserver3/app/jdk1.6.0_45/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
[root@qaserver3 qaserver3]#
```

when I run `echo $M2_HOME` I get the correct home path
`/home/qaserver3/app/maven-2.2.1`

The above home path I have set in Jenkins.

```
Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Maven ->  Maven installations ->  
    MAVEN_HOME = /home/qaserver3/app/maven-2.2.1
```

beloo I get a warining saying :

> `home/qaserver3/app/maven-2.2.1 is not a directory on the Jenkins
>   master (but perhaps it exists on some slaves)'

but when I build the project I get this error

**Console Output**

> ERROR: Maven Home /home/qaserver3/app/maven-2.2.1 doesn’t exist

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Does the Jenkins user have the read/execute rights on the `/home/qaserver3/app/maven-2.2.1` directory and its items ? 
You wrote `echo $M2_HOME` is OK. But what about `cd $M2_HOME` ?

Comment: @ValBonn `[qaserver3@qaserver3 app]$ cd $M2_HOME`
`[qaserver3@qaserver3 maven-2.2.1]$ `

Comment: Really trying to use [Maven 2.2.1](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Give R/w permissions to your Jenkins user

```sh
chmod 0755 /home/qaserver3/
chmod -R 0755 /home/qaserver3/app/maven-2.2.1
```

Make ensure Jenkins can access all the files

```sh
sudo -iu jenkins
```

Run:

```sh
/home/qaserver3/app/maven-2.2.1/bin/mvn -v
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely to see this warning `'home/qaserver3/app/maven-2.2.1 is not a directory on the Jenkins master (but perhaps it exists on some slaves)'` when the path in your system information tab is different than you have provided in the environmental variable.

Go to manage `jenkins->system information->now` check the path of maven in the table.

Copy that path and paste it into the `MAVEN_HOME` field. 
The warning should be gone by now and save it

cheers!